# How to get the max value of each column for each group in a dataframe?

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe:

```
      X      Y      Z      A      B
1    7.9    0.2    0.6    0.3    0.75
2    8.9    0.2    0.1    0.8    0.60
3    8.9    0.2    0.9    0.0    0.45
4    4.3    0.3    2.3    0.3    0.35
5    7.8    0.3    2.0    0.6    0.36
6    8.9    0.3    1.3    0.4    0.34
7    1.2    3.4    4.0    3.0    3.50
8    7.8    9.0    0.0    9.0    9.50
```

The dataframe is grouped using the 'Y' column. In each group, I would like to get the average value for 'X' and max for 'Z', 'A', and 'B'.

The result should look like this:

```
      X      Y      Z       A      B
0   8.56    0.2    0.9     0.8    0.75
1   7.00    0.3    2.3     0.6    0.36
2   1.20    3.4    4.0     3.0    3.50
3   7.80    9.0    0.0     9.0    9.50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about a pandas dataframe you can use [`df.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html), specifying an aggregation function for each column.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [7.9, 8.9, 8.9, 4.3, 7.8, 8.9, 1.2, 7.8],
                   'Y': [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 3.4, 9.0],
                   'Z': [0.6, 0.1, 0.9, 2.3, 2.0, 1.3, 4.0, 0.0],
                   'A': [0.3, 0.8, 0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 3.0, 9.0],
                   'B': [0.75, 0.6, 0.45, 0.35, 0.36, 0.34, 3.5, 9.5]}))

df2 = df.groupby("Y", as_index=False).agg({"X":"mean",
                                           "Z":"max", 
                                           "A":"max", 
                                           "B":"max"})
```

gives

```py
>>> df2
     Y         X    Z    A     B
0  0.2  8.566667  0.9  0.8  0.75
1  0.3  7.000000  2.3  0.6  0.36
2  3.4  1.200000  4.0  3.0  3.50
3  9.0  7.800000  0.0  9.0  9.50
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the max values, you can try something like this:

```
max_value = max(df['column_name'].values)
```

A similar approach for getting the average as well.

Comment: I need to get the max value of Z, A, and B in each group. In the end, I should have 1 row per group.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, then the main thing here is how you are storing the data.
The first way on my mind (maybe not the best one) is dictionary of dictionaries

```
data = Dict("Y-value1" ==> Dict(\
                        "X" ==> [1, 2, 3]\
                        "Z" ==> [4, 5, 6]\
                        "A" ==> [7, 8, 9]\
                        "B" ==> [10, 11, 12])\
           "Y-value2" ==> Dict(\
                        "X" ==> [1, 2, 3]\
                        "Z" ==> [4, 5, 6]\
                        "A" ==> [7, 8, 9]\
                        "B" ==> [10, 11, 12])) # And so on
```

Then you could just use those standard functions for finding max, min and average (or write them by yourself)